# How to dismiss UISearchController after didSelectRow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

I have two UITableViewControllers, first one to show the table view data and the second one to handle the filtered search.

The problem i have is on the second UITableViewController where i have filtered results, when i tap on the cell to segue to another controller, the UISearchBar and keyboard on top is still there.

This doesn't happen on the first TableViewController.

Heres my storyboard, the bottom right TableViewController handles the filtered results.

[image]

Heres what it looks visually once i segue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
self.searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In didSelectRow should be ok

Answer (score 0):

May be below code could help:

Dissmiss keyboard in searchBar delegate method like,

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

OR

in DidSelectRow method write below code:

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

and you can also write `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in DidSelectRow method.

***Edit:***

OR

write below code in DidSelectRow method:

```
[[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: Only thing is, that theres no outlet for searchBar in the controller. Here's a link i followed to create UISearchController: http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/

Comment: try, [self.view endEditing:YES] in DidSelectRow method as i mentioned in answer@farhan

Comment: still stays there.

Comment: getting error: "use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

Comment: 'AppDelegate' is your AppDelegate class name@farhan

Comment: It still says the same error of use of undeclared identifier